# Robot Framework | download SSHLibrary | python2.7 :: how to fix the error : command 'gcc' failed exit status 1

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, download, automated-tests, robotframework

i want to download **SSHLibrary** in order to develop test automation but every time he asks me again from other libraries to download .... such as *****paramico pyasnl pynacl***** etc until I get to **cffi** but the problem he shows me an error I can not solve  {error : command 'gcc' failed exit status} 1...
you find it below

check screenshot below

[image]

knowing that I work with python 2.7